# Open popup alert wicket

Tags: java, jquery, wicket

How can I open a popup without using AjaxRequestTarget or open a pop up without a click event occurring (AjaxRequestTarget is fine)? I am using wicket/Java

Below is what i tried but however i receive a NullException

```
dialog = new MessageDialog("dialog", "Notice", "Decision Matches ", DialogButtons.OK_CANCEL, DialogIcon.WARN) {
          public void onClose(AjaxRequestTarget target, DialogButton button) {
          }
      };         
      AjaxRequestTarget target = RequestCycle.get().find(AjaxRequestTarget.class);
      dialog.open( target);
```

Comment: Always post your efforts with question at our community

Comment: added my code snippet to original post

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't working since you don't have an AjaxRequestTarget present when you just render your page. The easiest approach here would be to initiate an AjaxCallback after your page is loaded and trigger your logic there.

```
public class HomePage extends WebPage {
private AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior onPageLoadBehavior;

public HomePage(final PageParameters parameters) {
    super(parameters);

    (...)

    onPageLoadBehavior = new AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior() {

        @Override
        protected void respond(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            //will be called after Dom is ready
            dialog.open(target);
        }
    };
    add(onPageLoadBehavior);
}

@Override
public void renderHead(IHeaderResponse response) {
    super.renderHead(response);
    //OnDomReady execute our onPageLoadBehavior callback
    response.render(OnDomReadyHeaderItem.forScript(onPageLoadBehavior.getCallbackScript()));
}
}
```

Comment: I tried this method but ran into a render head exceptionCaused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.web.RecordSetPage.renderHead(RecordSetPage.java:3287)
 at org.apache.wicket.Component.renderHead(Component.java:4404)
 at org.apache.wicket.Component.renderHead(Component.java:2664)
 at org.apache.wicket.markup.renderStrategy.AbstractHeaderRenderStrategy.renderRo

Comment: com.web.RecordSetPage.renderHead(RecordSetPage.java:3287) - what exactly is null here?
"onSubmit()" -> you could use a AjaxSubmitLink for your form and add your custom ajax logic in the onSubmit() part of that.